# How are football scores centrally updated

Tags: football, officiating

I follow football scores using websites like [Flashscores](https://www.flashscore.co.uk/) that has live updates of goals etc. When a goal is scored (or any event like a red card, sub etc) in a game what is the process that happens between the event happening and it appearing on a website or eg as a goal on Sky Sports Soccer Saturday?

My hunch is that there is some league official at every match with a laptop and an Internet connection that reports back events to some database at league HQ. Then third parties like broadcasters, bookmakers and score websites poll this data. But I cant find any information on it at all.

To give scope to the question I'd be interested in the English Professional and Semi-Pro leagues. However info on how this happens in other countries is just as acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the website.

Flashscore, which you linked in your question, is made and managed by a Czech company that grew quite a lot throughout the years.

According to few interviews with their representatives that I read in my native tongue (Polish), there are various sources of scores and other updates. The main one, for popular events, is just people in their offices watching matches transmitted a bit faster than in TV on multiple screens and using their applications to quickly change scores and select appriopriate events or commentary messages.

Matches from lower leagues that are not broadcasted are usually updated with less info by trusted sources that are watching them live on-site.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you have links to the interviews?

Comment: I don't remember exact ones but https://sportowefakty.wp.pl/tenis/1007026/korzystaja-z-niej-miliony-polakow-oto-tajemnice-popularnej-aplikacji https://newonce.net/artykul/czesi-stworzyli-potwora-dlaczego-flashscore-stal-sie-globalnym-liderem-wynikow-zywo